# Filter results in query before they are returned with Neo4j Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, resultset

I have a query that can return a potentially huge number of rows. It is extremely critical that it is as fast as possible.

Is there a way to change what is RETURNED based on what is matched? Here is a simplified version of the query:

```
MATCH p=(x)-[*]->(y) WHERE x.n="a"
WITH p,y OPTIONAL MATCH (y)<-[]-(z)
RETURN DISTINCT p,z
```

If the OPTIONAL MATCH finds results then there is no need for the large set 'p' to be returned.

What I would like to do with the results is:

```
IF z has results THEN RETURN z ELSE RETURN p
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should work (it essentially produces 2 kinds of results):

```
MATCH p=(x)-[*]->(y) WHERE x.n="a"
OPTIONAL MATCH (y)<--(z)
RETURN DISTINCT
  CASE WHEN z IS NULL THEN {p: p} ELSE {z: z} END AS res;
```

*Note that unbounded patterns like `[*]` can take a long time (or never finish, or run out of memory) if you have a lot of data.*

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [coalesce()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/scalar/#functions-coalesce) function. It will return the first non-null value in the list of expressions passed to it. Try:

```
MATCH p=(x)-[*]->(y) WHERE x.n="a"
WITH p,y
OPTIONAL MATCH (y)<-[]-(z)
WITH coalesce(z, p) as result
RETURN DISTINCT result
```

Comment: This also looks like it will work in some cases, Thanks